# firebase-admin: Get token of failed notification delivery result

Tags: node.js, push-notification, firebase-admin

Let's say we want to send a notification to two registrationTokens (only Android devices, no iOS) like this:

```
const tokens = ['tokenA', 'tokenB'];

const payload = {badge: 1, title: 'Hello', body: 'world'};
const options = {priority: 'high',contentAvailable: false, timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24};

const admin = FirebaseAdmin.initializeApp({/*config here...*/});

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceTokens, payload, options)
  .then((response) => {

    response.results.forEach((deviceResult) => {
      if (deviceResult.error) {
        console.log('Delivery failed. Showing result:\n', deviceResult);
      }
    });

});
```

The user who's device once registered with `tokenB` deleted the app from his device. Therefore the token is not registered anymore with firebase.
The error object looks like this then:

`Delivery failed. Showing result:`

```
{"error":
  {
    "code":"messaging/registration-token-not-registered",
    "message":"The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages."
  }
}
```

**The Problem:**
My problem is, that I only know that one of the deliveries failed. But I don't know to which token the error is related. Therefore I cannot remove the outdated token from the database.

**The Question:**
Is there a way to find out for which tokens the deliveries have failed?

Github Issue Link: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/600

Comment: FYI: I've created a GitHub issue on that topic: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/600

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the index in `forEach` and get the token from your array you passed in `sendToDevice`.

Official docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MessagingDevicesResponse

This seems like a hack but it works for me when I have multiple device tokens of a single user as I have to store new one whenever they login.

```
const tokens = ['tokenA', 'tokenB'];

const payload = {badge: 1, title: 'Hello', body: 'world'};
const options = {priority: 'high',contentAvailable: false, timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24};

const admin = FirebaseAdmin.initializeApp({/*config here...*/});

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceTokens, payload, options)
  .then((response) => {

    response.results.forEach((deviceResult,index) => {
      if (deviceResult.error) {
        let failedToken = tokens[index];
        // Now use this token to delete it from your DB, or mark it failed according to your requirements.
      }
    });

});
```

This method is also used in firbease samples as well: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a valuable information, which I could use for a workaround. I wonder how reliable this is, I don't want to risk to remove registered tokens. In case this is the `correct way to do it`, the firebase guys should add that to their documentation.

Comment: yes they should add it to documentation. Regarding reliability I think the response from FCM server keeps the order of the array, seeing the implementation code in the above mentioned link.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't like to "assume" that FCM keeps the order of the array. I need proof. A note in the docs would be sufficient.

Comment: I will mention your solution in the GitHub issue I recently created github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/600

Comment: add the link to their sample as well in the issue.

Comment: Turns out this already is documented in the docs. Would you please add this link to you answer? I will accept it then: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MessagingDevicesResponse.html#results

Comment: Updated my answer